# run values from array into "gift_id":

Tags: arrays, function, actionscript-3, return

I'm learning actionscript 3 and trying to get values from the array to be passed one after another into "gift_id": , and basically reward gifts. I am not totally sure if it could be done like this or the best way to achieve it. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
public function userGift(): Object {
    var gift_id: Array = [2373, 9383, 4444, 4557, 8737];
    return {
        "change_type": "accepted",
        "gift_id": ,
    };
}
```

Comment: I was thinking I could maybe use something like the following although I'm not sure on it:- if (gift_id="accepted") { return {

Comment: Please explain your actual goal and not the problems of the solution that you came up with, see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Explain what you want to achieve in the end, but not in the programming terms, which you don't quite understand yet. Describe in basic English what you want to do.

Comment: my goal is to award multiple gifts to users by passing id number for each gift thorugh gift_id:

Comment: I for one cannot help you if you merely restate your unclear question. Please provide a big picture view of your project and what this function is supposed to do, how it is used, what you want to achieve in the end.

Comment: I'm guessing you want the `userGift()` function to return different values according to some state or condition. A function cannot do this on its own, you need to either pass parameters into the function or use some persistent data outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Function can only return single object, so I don't think this is a good way to do it. If you want to reuse it, you can call it multiple times if you pass id as a parameter.

```
var giftsArray:Array = [];
for each(var id:int in gift_id) {
    giftsArray.push( userGift(id) );
}
//You should have an Array full of gift objects.
trace(giftsArray.length);

public function userGift(id:int):Object {
    return {
        "change_type": "accepted",
        "gift_id": id,
    };
}
```